# Asynchronous Tree Traversal in Node.js

Tags: node.js, recursion, tree, nested, nested-loops

I'm trying to traverse a tree of nested of items in Node.js and I keep running into a range of issues. I've looked around at various stackoverflow questions and answers, some of them recommend using a library like async. This should be possible in raw node.js though.

```
var count=0;
exports.buildFamily = function(item_id, mback){
var extendedFamily={};

exports.getItembyId(item_id, function(err, item){
    extendedFamily=item;
    if(item.descendants){
        extendedFamily.kids=[];
        count=+item.descendants.length;
        item.descendants.forEach(function(element, index, array){

            console.log('deepcount: ' + count);
            count--

            exports.buildFamily(element, function(err, family){
                extendedFamily.kids.push(family)
                if(count==0){ return mback(null, extendedFamily);}
                else {extendedFamily.kids.push(family);}
            })
       });
    }
    else{
      if(count==0){ return mback(null, extendedFamily);}
      else{return;}
      }
    });

};
```

Comment: *"I keep running into a range of issues"* please expand on this. What are the issues? What's wrong with the code you have provided?

Comment: Sorry, I've reimplemented it a bunch of times. This particular version calls the `done` callback `mback` before the traversal is done and passes to it an incomplete family. This I'm guessing is because of the count variable, which zeroes out before it ought to. My guess is that this is either because `forEach()` is not actually blocking(it should be blocking) or there's some sort of type issue.

Comment: forEach is blocking, but the asynchronous method within it is not.

Comment: I guess that means people don't mean the same thing as I do when I say 'blocking'.

Comment: by blocking, i mean, the method is executed to completion before the code after it begins. but asynchronous methods within always break out of that.

Comment: I thought the whole thing, the `forEach` and whatever is done `forEach` was blocking. I.e. for each one it does that stuff, and then it does the same for the next.

Comment: Nothing can make a blocking method wait on an asynchronous one.

Comment: So, I've replaced the forEach with an `async.eachSeries`. It almost works. It still returns an incomplete family, missing a second level element, but getting a lower level element.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33029160/asynchronous-tree-traversal-using-async-js